# GCC: How to generate line number debug information only?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, compilation

I would like to improve the build speed of a large project. The opt build is compiled with -O2 -g. I noticed that without -g, compilation becomes faster, about 10-20%. The resulting binary has enough information to analyze crashes, except for the line numbers. Is there a way to include line number information but nothing else?

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html, line numbers are produced only at level 2 (i.e. -g2 or the default of -g) or above. But according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission, line numbers are only a fraction of the debug information (1%). So for me it would be best to have -g0 or -g1 but with line numbers. Is this possible?

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Answer is still to use -g1. It does generate a little bit more than just line tables though:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101470

Comment: And since in clang -gline-tables-only is an alias for -g1 it can be used for both compilers: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/4c642b62b99fa128c180f28278637b32be5e5576/clang/include/clang/Driver/Options.td#L4150

Answer (score 7):

Googling the Clang option mentioned by Matthieu, I found a patch for gcc that does what I want. It has been submitted for trunk but has been pending since two years. This means stock GCC is not able to do this, but with this patch it can do it using the option "-gmlt"

http://old.nabble.com/-patch--Add-new--gmlt-option-for-min.-debug-info-with-line-tables-%28issue4440072%29-td31482851.html

Comment: Well done! I tried googling the option as well but did not get anything in gcc. It's a shame the patch is still pending, you might want to bump it/express your interest in it.

Comment: I guess this never got merged:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Answer (score 6):

Could you be mistaken ? I know that [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-size-of-debug-information) supports `-gline-tables-only`, however as far as I could see gcc does not; it does support `-g1`, but there is no line information.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I also found this patch submitted to gcc which allows gcc to do the same, however it seems to be pending since some time.

Comment: Is there a way to strip the excessive debug info generated by GCC? For example, many strings in the `.debug_str` section are unnecessary, but the file names and function names are also there, so we shouldn't strip the entire section.

Answer (score 3):

Time has passed.

GCC know includes line numbers with `-g1`.

You can also add two more options to save more space: `-g1 -gz -gsplit-dwarf`